# On click event of One Dropdown list other sibling component dropdown list not Loading

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 different components having a dropdown list for one for the district and other for Mandal I want to load district at page load at 3rd Component but Mandal at click event of District Component dropdown list.
But when I am clicking on district DDL its firing method but not loading mandal it's showing IsEditable False.[image: Mandal.component]

[image: Mandal.html[![District.Component]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDMT4.png)

[image: District.html]

Answer (score 0):

I cant see how you use the MondalComponent but I would introduce a @Input to that component and let it bind to selectedDay component member an the remove SelectChangeHandler.
It could look something like this

```
<div app-mondal [day]="selectedDay"></div>.
```

The day @Input could be an setter so that you could call populate inside it

```
@Input set selectedDay(value:string){...}
```

You should consider remove Injectable from DistrictComponent. I often use that on services